# Save an Image instance as png Magick++

Tags: c++, magick++

This is my 3<sup>rd</sup> subsequent post about Magick++ even though I spend tons of effort trying to deal with it myself.

I have this program:

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv)
{

  // Initialize ImageMagick install location for Windows
  InitializeMagick(*argv);

  try {

    Image button;
    Geometry size = Geometry(10,10);
    button.size(size);
    button.write("button_out.png");
  }
  catch( exception &error_ )
    {
      cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << endl;
      system("Pause");
      return 1;
    }
  /*
  */
  
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see all I'm trying to do is to save 10x10 empty image to a png file. Unfortunately, Magick++ can't do that:

```
Caught exception: stripes.exe: no encode delegate for this image format `' @ err
or/constitute.c/WriteImage/1167
Pokračujte stisknutím libovolné klávesy...
```

That's a big disappointment. I spent six hours getting the library to work to end up with this. But I think Magick++ is capable of doing it, eventually. Therefore the question is, what have I done wrong?

Should I somewhere include/require/load some module that allows `PNG` saving?

Comment: Try saving it as a GIF or JPEG for a moment just to see if everything else works. If it does, the problem is that you have not correctly installed the PNG delegate, or some aspect of it as @rafalon suggests.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Gif is the only thing that seems to work.

Comment: Well, that tells us that your code and compilation process are correct, so the problem is with the installation of the delegates - these are `helper tools` that ImageMagick uses to get various standard jobs done. You can download them from here... http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/

Comment: Tese are some archives with source code? What should I do with them...? Why is everything so complicated? :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you put DLL's in your binary folder? You know that PNG is compressed by zlib, right? For example: when you using SDL library and you use PNG's you need to put zlib and libpng DLL's in bin folder to allow program reading and writing PNG files.

Comment: These are the only dlls that seem useable: `CORE_RL_bzlib_.dll`, `CORE_RL_jpeg_.dll`, `CORE_RL_png_.dll`, `CORE_RL_zlib_.dll`
`IM_MOD_RL_png_.dll`. I copied them to both program location and program working directory. Neither solved the problem. Could you tell me more about loading DLLs?

Comment: I'm not competent to talk about loading DLLs, but Magick as most of libs loads DLLs on its own.

Comment: I meaan, where the hell should I get those dll's?

Comment: You search in google for example: "libpng for windows" first link.